# Why isnt this test returning True?

Tags: python, string, list

trying to convert a text file into a string, and this is the test our teacher gave us which is supposed to print true:

```
test_text = """This is a small sentence. This isn't a small sentence, because
this sentence contains more than 10 words and a number! This isn't
a question, is it?"""

test_tm = TextModel( "Milestone test" )  # create a TextModel object

text = test_tm.readTextFromFile( "test.txt" )
print "Is text == test_text? ", text == test_text
```

and here's my code:

```
class TextModel:

    def __init__(self, name):
        """ the constructor for the TextModel class
            all dictionaries are started at empty
            the name is just for our own purposes, to keep things 
            organized
        """
        self.name = name
        self.words = {}   # starts empty
        self.wordlengths = {}
        self.stems = {}
        self.sentencelengths = {}
        # you will want another dictionary for your text feature


    def __repr__(self):
        """ this method creates the string version of TextModel objects
        """
        s  = "\nModel name: " + str(self.name) + "\n"
        s += "    n. of words: " + str(len(self.words))  + "\n"
        s += "    n. of word lengths: " + str(len(self.wordlengths))  + "\n"
        s += "    n. of sentence lengths: " + str(len(self.sentencelengths))  + "\n"
        s += "    n. of stems: " + str(len(self.stems))  + "\n"
        # you will likely want another line for your custom text-feature!
        return s

    def readTextFromFile(self, filename):
        # f = open( filename, "r" )
        # text = f.read()
        # f.close()
        f = file( filename )
        text = f.read()
        words = text.split()
        return words
```

not sure why these things need to be equal to each other, but it's important that they are for further along in the program.

Answer (score 0):

`readTextFromFile` is calling `.split()` on the string you read in, so it's a `list` of the "words" (segments of non-whitespace text) from the input file. The test string is just a single string which you never split. A `list` is never equal to a `str`.

Perhaps you meant to test?

```
text == test_text.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's returning false because you're comparing a list and a string. The variable `test_text` contains a string, but `text` contains the return value from `test_tm.readTextFromFile()`. The return value is a list of the words, since in the definition of `TextModel.readTextFromFile` you return `words`, which is the split version of the text that was read. It seems likely that you're just returning the wrong value. If you change it to return `text` from the function instead of `words`, it should work like you expect.